# how to link to unit-tests/2017.html?

Tags: cobalt

we test Youtube qual-e with cobalt RELEASE_9.
we see the default MSE testing is 2018.html but desktop version is 2017.html.
we found Youtube qual-e JS (navigation.js) will check application(navigator.userAgent) to redirect target address.

do you know we need to remove cobalt in navigator.userAgent or other way to test 2017.html by Youtube official website?

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt MSE/EME versions exceed the MSE/EME versions that YouTube 2017 Technical Requirements requires. So please use that 2018.html MSE/EME/Progressive test cases for Cobalt based device even for 2017 certification.